Can GKE POD Horizontal Autoscaling be available with Memory Utilization Metrics through Terraform IAC?
I need to enable GKE POD Horizontal Autoscaling with Memory Utilization Metrics through Terraform IAC. I found code with CPU Utilization, but not with Memory Utilization Metrics in Terraform registry.
I also tried with the following code but got the below error after applying Terraform pipeline:
ERROR Message:
[2024-07-09 10:50:07] Error: the server could not find the requested resource
[2024-07-09 10:50:07]
[2024-07-09 10:50:07] releases, based on feedback.
[2024-07-09 10:50:07]
[2024-07-09 10:50:07] If you have feedback on the design of this feature, please open a GitHub issue
[2024-07-09 10:50:07] to discuss it.
[2024-07-09 10:50:07]
[2024-07-09 10:50:07] (and 7 more similar warnings elsewhere)
[2024-07-09 10:50:07]
[2024-07-09 10:50:07] on .terraform/modules/query_service_dev1.query_service/k8s_hpa.tf line 32, in resource "kubernetes_horizontal_pod_autoscaler" "hpa":
[2024-07-09 10:50:07] 32: resource "kubernetes_horizontal_pod_autoscaler" "hpa"

Terraform Code with Plan:
resource "kubernetes_horizontal_pod_autoscaler" "hpa" {  
  metadata {
        labels = {
          "app"     = "query-service"
          "dept"    = "Sentinels"
          "name"    = "query-service"
          "part-of" = "Foundry"
        }
        name             = "query-service"
        namespace        = "dev1-e2-dev1-ssrs-query"
  }

  spec {
    min_replicas = 1
    max_replicas = 3
    scale_target_ref {
      api_version = "apps/v1"
      kind = "Deployment"
      name = local.deployment_metadata[0]["name"] #"demo"
    }
    metric {   
      type = "Resource"
      resource {
        name = "cpu"
        target {
          type = "Utilization"
          average_utilization = "80"
        }
      }
    }
    metric {
      type = "Resource"
      resource {
        name = "memory"
        target {
          type = "Utilization"
          average_utilization = "80"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

